# Efficient/Single trigger of ng-change on textbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Let's say I have the following array in an angular controller:

```
somelist = [ 
             { name: 'John',  dirty: false },
             { name: 'Max',   dirty: false },
             { name: 'Betty', dirty: false }
           ];
```

I want to ng-repeat through it in my view, and generate editable fields for each record:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in somelist">
     <input type="text" ng-model="i.name"/>
</div>
```

How would I go about efficiently marking the field as dirty if someone edits the textbox(model)?

I realize that I could use ng-change on the text field, however, that fires every time a user makes a single change(enters a key) on the textbox, making loads of calls unnecessarily.. Is there a more efficient way of doing this which I am missing?

Comment: Do you have heavy operations to do in this event handler? If not, you shouldn't really worry about "unnecessary calls", that's micro-optimization. If yes, you can look at [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

Comment: I think you are looking for [debouncing updates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#debouncing-updates). `<input type="text" ng-model="i.name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"/>`

Comment: @Kaddath Thanks, ng-blur is closer to what I was looking for. Like you say, it is not a huge concern, even if there was a heavy operation you could just evaluate a temporary bool to see if it's already been changed and cut out the operation. But I have encountered this a few times recently and it seems a bit sloppy to make all these calls for no reason. Wanted to know if there is something in place which caters for it

Comment: @Hasta Tamag Also an interesting solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript...
*Edited: if that textareas don't have any other 'change' event to run, you can try inline onchange event, and replace it's value after have run once. Just making `onchange="once(this)"` become into this — `onchange=""` *In background. The code will still stay in your HTML. Demo:

(also exist `input` and `keyup` events... in Angular as well)

```js
function once(e){
  e.style.color="red";
  e.onchange = "";
  
  //just demo... remove this.
  const d = document.getElementById('demo');
  d.innerText = Number(d.innerText) + 1;
 }
```

```html
<textarea class="moo" onchange="once(this)">Change me!</textarea>
<textarea class="moo" onchange="once(this)">Me too!</textarea>
<textarea class="moo" onchange="once(this)">And me!</textarea>
<br><br>
Triggered times: <span id="demo">0</span>
```

---

Running eventListener function once (not really):

```js
let once = [];//creating empty array
const moo = document.getElementsByClassName('moo');//getting all textareas
for(let i = 0; i < moo.length; i++ ){//looping, to add 'change' event to each element
  once.push(1);//adding '1' to array 'i' times. Here it will look like [1,1,1];
  moo[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(once[i]==0){return}//if array element equals 0 = return and don't run the function
    this.style.color = "red";
    once[i] = 0;//after triggered = making array element = 0;
    
    //just demo... remove this.
    const d = document.getElementById('demo');
    d.innerText = Number(d.innerText) + 1;
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea class="moo">Change me!</textarea>
<textarea class="moo">Me too!</textarea>
<textarea class="moo">And me!</textarea>
<br><br>
Triggered times: <span id="demo">0</span>
```

*function is still working each time... but returning immediately, which is better, than "full" run.

Comment: Thanks, however, I am looking for something that is part of the angular framework already which can be used. Adding this kind of operation would most likely be more costly than just having multiple calls to the event handler.

Comment: As I thought... Angular is a JavaScript framework, which is remaking easy-looking code to a real JS in background (which is a +1 extra step)... and pure JS would be better for "performance". But in reality, now we have so powerful machines, that +/-0.1 sec of waiting means nothing))

Answer (score 0):

To improve efficiency, reduce the number of *watchers* by using `::` and eliminating two-way binds, e.g.`ng-model`:

`<div ng-repeat="i in ::somelist">
    <input type="text" value="{{i.name}}" 
        ng-blur="$emit('nameChanged', i)"/>
</div>`

Then, in your controller:

`$scope.$on('nameChanged', (event, i) => updateName(i));`

Then a quick, simple function that updates the name with the corresponding ID using `i.id` and `i.name`, assuming you have:

`$scope.someList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Max' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Betty }'`

**Explanation**

If people aren't going to be added/removed from the list, then you can use `::` on `someList`, also known as a *one-time binding*, to improve efficiency.   This circumvents setting up a *watcher*.

Also, by setting value=`{{i.name}}`, you effectively set up a *one-way bind* from the controller to the DOM, rather than two-way, meaning that the value of the input isn't being checked every loop of the `$digest` cycle, but any changes to the model will update the DOM.

Just an idea, feel free to play with variations, such as dropping blur and using a single button that would update all changed fields at once.

You won't get much more efficient than that, unless you also remove the watcher from `value="{{i.name}}"` like so `value="{{::i.name}}"`, and then you manually update the DOM when the event is received.